# Proof of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove or disprove the following:

If $A \cap B⊆\overline C $ and $A∪C⊆B$, then $A \cap C =\emptyset$

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Since A subset B, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Suppose that x belongs to A Inter C and try to derive a contradiction. This will allow you to conclude anything you want ( in virtue of the " principle of explosion")  , and in particular, that x belongs to the empty set; and therefore, that A Inter C is included in the empty set. ( With the reverse inclusion resulting from the definiiton of the empty set, the goal, namely, reciprocal inclusion, is easily reachable).
- In order to derive a contradiction, you will have to use 2 rules

(1) the equivalent of contraposition for sets : "X included in Y" iff " complement of Y included in complement of X"

(2) De Morgan's laws for sets

complement of (X union Y) =  intersection of complement of X and of complement of Y

complement of ( X Inter Y) = union of complement of X and of complement of Y.

- You may start in the following way : If x belongs to A Inter C, x belongs to C; if x belongs to C, then...